Real Analysis: Equivalent statements of limit superior
I am confused about the proof (highlighted part) given by the author. Can anyone help me with it?
My Question:
I can't see how the author derive the conclusion $x^* \in S$ simply based on the preceding statement. Besides, it appears to me that it's unnecessary to claim that "$x^* \in S$", since $x^* \leq s < x^*+\epsilon$ is sufficient to imply that there are at most finitely many natural number n such that $x^* + \epsilon < x_n$.
Theorem:

If $(x_{n})$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, then the following statements for a real number $x^*$ are equivalent:

$x^* = \lim \sup(x_{n})$
If $\epsilon>0$, there are at most finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^*+\epsilon<x_{n}$, and infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^*-\epsilon<x_{n}$


Proof:

$1. \Rightarrow 2.$: Let $\epsilon>0$. Sicne $x^*$ is an infimum, then there exists some $s\in S$ such that $x^* \leq s < x^*+\epsilon$. Therefore $x^* \in S$, so there are at most finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^*+\epsilon<x_{n}$. On the other hand, $x^*-\epsilon$ is not in $V$ so there are an infinite number of $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $x^*-\epsilon<x_{n}$.

Here is the definition of limit superior given in the textbook:

Let $(x_{n})$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. The limit superior of $(x_{n})$ is the infimum of the set $S$ of elements $s\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $s<x_{n}$ for at most finitely number of $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, i.e., $$\lim \inf(x_{n}) = \inf\{s\in \mathbb{R}:s<x_{n} \mathrm{~for~at~most~finitely~many~} n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$$


This is just a  typo. $x^{}$ in the highlighted part should be $x^{}+\epsilon$.

@geetha290krm That still isn't correct, unless you assume that $S$ is convex.

@SebastianMueller Any number larger than an element of $S$ belongs to $S$.

FYI, my textbook is Introduction to Real Anaysis by Robert Bartle.

I don't think that that is correct.
Consider the sequence $x_n=(\frac{1}{n})$ and $S=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $x^*=\limsup(x_n)=0\not\in S$.
The theorem itself seems to be correct, though.
